# What is the earliest comic book that features an antihero superhero?

Tags: comics

What is the first instance of a comic book/graphic novel that features a "hero" that does not fit a truly heroic personality?  These are individuals that most of the world (in the comics) views as "good" superheroes, but the morals, goals and actions of the characters seem to be opposed to their perceived public persona.

Examples would be:

- Watchmen - Ozymandius "uniting" the world.
- The Boys - Homelander letting the plane crash. (Well, most of the supes from the Boys could fit into this).
- Marshal Law - the character is a super-police officer who hunts other superheroes who have committed horrific crimes.
- Suicide Squad - Amanda Waller does things for "the greater good" but they are not "good".

What would not fit:

- The Punisher (the world views him as a vigilante even though he may occasionally do good things)
- V - same as the Punisher
- Magneto - viewed as a villain by most of the Marvel populace.

Comment: What degree of dystopia are you looking for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_antiheroes#Comic_books might be a start.

Comment: Any really.  I'm not even sure if that is the correct term to use.  I basically want to avoid the Punisher and Wolverine and focus more on stories where "heroes" are imperfect.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I found that list, but considering that it is missing a large number of examples I mention above (Watchmen for example), and includes a bunch of examples that I don't consider dystopian (Sub-Mariner), I thought the list was incomplete.

Comment: Your use of dystopian is confusing me. Are you specifically looking for a anti-hero from a messed up world?

Comment: @Boelabaal - I mention in a comment that I am not sure dystopian is the correct word (I'm not sure if that is contributing to the downvotes?).  What I am looking for are instances where there are superheroes that are above "normal" people and use their powers in non-heroic ways.  Ozymandias trying to "unite" the world; Homelander letting the plane crash to prove a point are the type of actions I would expect the "heroes" to exhibit.  So, dystopian may not be appropriate, but I'm looking for the earliest non-traditional (e.g. DC and Marvel) stories that exhibit superheroes gone bad.

Comment: @APrough - *Gilgamesh and Enkidu* fits your description

Comment: @Valorum - technically the stories of a lot of gods probably fit into the general description, but I'm specifically looking for comics.  Unless there's a graphic novel about Gilgamesh somewhere out there (which would probably be fascinating).

Comment: So many downvotes but no reasons why.  How can I improve this question?

Comment: I think a lot of it probably comes down to a combination of that some people don't like the "first example" questions because they're sometimes a dodge to avoid list questions, and because the "correct" answer kind of comes down to whoever has posted the most recent older example.

Comment: Also, as is evidenced by the comment discussion, the meanings of "superheroes" and "dystopian" are vaguely enough defined that it's hard to know exactly what you're looking for. I think you are looking for people beyond the power of mere mortals who do morally sketchy things. Still not certain if they still need either a degree of heroicism or at least a public belief that they hold such a status. It is good that it's limited to the first comic where they showed up rather than "first instance" as per Valorum's comment on *Gilgamesh*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots.  Thanks for the feedback.  I found that interesting because I see a lot of questions on here about "first instance of X" that have quite a few upvotes.  I'll see if I can reword my question somehow....

Comment: Your edits don't improve the clarity of the question

Comment: I also dislike "first" / list questions with a dozen qualifiers. If it needs so many qualifiers "this, but not that - and I don't want this either" then it's just a bad question imo (I've probably written a couple myself like that so it's not an attack on the poster btw :) )

Comment: Well, I guess just leave this closed and maybe others will see it and learn a lesson from it.

Comment: The Badger. Mostly heroic, sometimes anti-heroic, always insane.

Answer (score 1):

One possible early example would be [Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_(character)), introduced in July of 1973. He lives in a dystopic world where vampires are everywhere, and prey upon humans more or less at will. Blade himself is a hero in that he fights the vampires, but he is stated as doing so not because of benevolence to the humans around him, but rather due to his hatred of the vampires.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your perspective of "superhero", [Conan the Barbarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_the_Barbarian) lives in an era where violence is common and people are regularly oppressed, and had his first comic book outing in *Cuentos de Abuelito #8* in 1952. Conan himself is a hero in that he fights various tyrants and monsters, but his motivation is basically that of conquest and personal improvement.